# Start Process which calls a powershell script error output

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a c# console app which calls a powershell script as you can see below. If there are any errors in the powershell script, i'd love for it to report back the error to the c# console and then break in the console. How does one go about that? A code example would be greatly appreciated.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = argFinal;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Also, the powershell script itself calls some things like 7-zip and such. If they error, i would also like to capture that. Not sure if that'd work differently based on being called from powershell and not the c# console app itself.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, C# programs can host PowerShell runtime directly, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `RedirectStandardError` property to true.  Then you can read the `StandardError` stream on the Process object to get any error text.  See this [MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.